# Combination of String array and Radom

Tags: arrays, string, random

I want to have an array which randomly gives me one of the given answers. But Java says "array[hallo] not possible; you use String but int is expected"
Is there a possibility to solve this problem or am I all wrong?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class ZufallsAntworten
{

private Random ran;

public ZufallsAntworten()
{
    ran = new Random();
}

public int richtigeAntwort()
{
    String[]array = new String[100];
    array[0]="a";
    array[1]="b";
    array[2]="c";
    array[3]="d";
    int hallo = ran.nextInt(array.length+1);
    return array[hallo];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method `richtigeAntwort()` returns an `int`, but you are returning a `String`, since your array is an array of Strings. This line:

```
return array[hallo];
```

will fetches one of the Strings from your array at that index and return it.

I cannot read the name of your method so I cannot advice you much beyond simply changing the return type of the `richtigeAntwort()` method to `String`.